# MIME media type application/xml was not found

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I'm using, Maven, Jersey and PostGres.

For a school project, I try to develop a Generic Rest Service but I've got an error and I don't know how to fix it.

When I want to GET one entity by the id it works fine . I have the XML generated files from my Database.

But when I want all the entities in my Database I have the error :

> mars 31, 2016 7:12:46 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
>   GRAVE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.Vector, and Java type class java.util.Vector, and MIME media type application/xml was not found.

This is the AbstractResourceRest class where the error seems to be :

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public abstract class AbstractResourceRest<PK extends Serializable,
    T extends IdentifiableEntity<PK>> implements IResourceRest<PK, T> {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractResourceRest.class);
    private int maxPageSize = 500;

    @Override
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public T find(@PathParam("id") PK id) throws DAOException {
        T result = getGenericManager().find(id);
        getGenericManager().done();
        return result;
    }

    //todo: use CDI (hk2) instead ?
    public abstract IRestManager<PK, T> getGenericManager();

    @Override
    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void delete(@PathParam("id") PK id) throws DAOException {
        System.out.println("DELETE OK");
        getGenericManager().delete(id);
        getGenericManager().done();
    }

    @Override
    public long size() throws DAOException {
        long result = getGenericManager().getSize();
        getGenericManager().done();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @HEAD
    public Response metadata() throws DAOException {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .header("X-Total-Item-Count", size())
                .header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Total-Item-Count, X-Total-Page-Count").build();
    }

    @Override
    @GET
    public Response findAll(@QueryParam("reverse") @DefaultValue("false") boolean reverse,
                            @QueryParam("pagenumber") @DefaultValue("-1") int pageNumber,
                            @QueryParam("perpage") @DefaultValue("-1") int perPage,
                            @QueryParam("limit") @DefaultValue("-1") int limit,
                            @Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws DAOException {
        System.out.println("pageNumber = " + pageNumber);
        Response response;
        if (pageNumber == -1)
            response=listToResponse(getGenericManager().findAll(reverse, limit), uriInfo)
                    .build();
        else {
            if (perPage < 0) perPage = getMaxPageSize();
            LOGGER.info("pre findall");
            Page result = getGenericManager().findAllByPage(reverse, pageNumber, perPage, limit);
            LOGGER.info("post findall");
            response = pageToResponse(result, uriInfo)
                    .build();
            LOGGER.info("post response built");
        }
        getGenericManager().done();
        return response;
    }

    protected Response.ResponseBuilder listToResponse(List<T> list, UriInfo uriInfo) throws DAOException {
       //I try with : GenericEntity<List<T>> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<List<T>>(list){};

       return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(list);

    }

    protected Response.ResponseBuilder pageToResponse(Page page, UriInfo uriInfo) throws DAOException {
        List<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
        if (page.PAGE_NUMBER > 0) {
            links.add("<" + uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + "?pagenumber=0" + "&perpage=" + page.PAGE_SIZE + ">; rel=\"first\"");
            links.add("<" + uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + "?pagenumber=" + (page.PAGE_NUMBER + 1) + "&perpage=" + page.PAGE_SIZE + ">; rel=\"previous\"");
        }
        if (page.PAGE_NUMBER < page.TOTAL_PAGES - 1) {
            links.add("<" + uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + "?pagenumber=" + (page.PAGE_NUMBER + 1) + "&perpage=" + page.PAGE_SIZE + ">; rel=\"next\"");
            links.add("<" + uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + "?pagenumber=" + (page.TOTAL_PAGES - 1) + "&perpage=" + page.PAGE_SIZE + ">; rel=\"last\"");
        }

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(page.content)
                .header("Link", links.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
                .header("X-Total-Item-Count", page.TOTAL_ITEMS)
                .header("X-Total-Page-Count", page.TOTAL_PAGES)
                .header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Total-Item-Count, X-Total-Page-Count");
    }

    @Override
    @GET
    @Path("ids")
    public List<PK> getIds(@QueryParam("reverse") @DefaultValue("false") boolean reverse) throws DAOException {
        List<PK> result = getGenericManager().getIds(reverse);
        getGenericManager().done();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @PUT
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    public T create(T item) throws DAOException {
        T result = getGenericManager().create(item);
        getGenericManager().done();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @PUT
    @Path("collection")
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    public int create(List<T> list) throws DAOException {
        int result = getGenericManager().create(list);
        getGenericManager().done();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    public T update(T t) throws DAOException {
        T result = getGenericManager().update(t);
        getGenericManager().done();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @DELETE
    public int delete() throws DAOException {
        System.out.println("DELETE");
        int result = getGenericManager().deleteAll();
        getGenericManager().done();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @GET
    @Path("maxpagesize")
    public int getMaxPageSize() {
        return maxPageSize;
    }

    @Override
    @PUT
    @Path("maxpagesize")
    public void setMaxPageSize(int pageSize) {
        this.maxPageSize = pageSize;
    }
}
```

I found that in the listToResponse method , the List list parameter is expected to be a Vector, but I never used Vector in the whole project.

I tried to use

```
GenericEntity<List<T>> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<List<T>>(list){};
```

But I've got the same error.

This is my pom.xml in case of need :

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target> 1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source> 1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <java.version>          1.8</java.version>
    <eclipselink.version> 2.5.2</eclipselink.version>
    <javax.persistence>   2.1.0</javax.persistence>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava-testlib</artifactId>
      <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>

<!--<dependency>-->
  <!--<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>-->
  <!--<artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>-->
  <!--<version>${javax.persistence}</version>-->
  <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--</dependency>-->
<!--<dependency>-->
  <!--<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>-->
  <!--<artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>-->
  <!--<version>${eclipselink.version}</version>-->
  <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
<!--</dependency>-->


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
  <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
  <version>0.99</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you have any idea, 
Thanks for all !!

Comment: I'm not using Servlet and Jetty

Comment: your pom file is messy. You mix in there different jersey versions and also different json mapping libs. Clean it up and I am pretty sure it will then work.